# How to change div background color only when it is being scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, background-color

Till now I have managed to do till this point--

After a certain pixel from page top the div changes it's background color.

But I want to change the background-color of that div only when it is being scrolled. Once the div has been scrolled past I want to change it's background color back to previous one.

**This is the code that I have tried**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>50){
   
    $('.q_ans_sec').attr('id', 'scrolled_fixedDiv');
        } else {
           $('.q_ans_sec').removeAttr('id');
        }
        
        });
```

```css
.container-fluid {
    background-color:blue;
    height:500px;
    }
    
#scrolled_fixedDiv.container-fluid {
    background-color: red;
}
.nxtdiv {
height:500px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid q_ans_sec">
</div>
<div class="nxtdiv">
</div>
```

As you can see in the above example when you scroll up it is still red and changes its color to blue only when the scroll is less than 50px.

I want it to be blue when I scroll up again. Any idea how to achieve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't understand the downvote..the question is very specific!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height()*0.5)
```

Try to retrieve the page height using `$(document).height()`. If you want the viewport height, then you will need to use `$(window).height()`.

Comment: Try if($(window).scrollTop()>($(window).height()/2)){